# In functional components, how do I reformat multiple change handlers in a single function?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm writing a simple React program, which features three inputs. When the user inputs text, the data is captured and saved to state, as follows:

```
const [name, setName] = useState('')
  const [chore, setChore] = useState('')
  const [date, setDate] = useState('')
  const [document, setDocument] = useState<ChoreDoc | null>(null);
  const [choreList, setChoreList] = useState<Array<ChoreDoc>>([])

  const handleNameChange = (e:React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
      e.preventDefault()
      setName(e.currentTarget.value)
  }
  const handleChoreChange = (e:React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
      e.preventDefault()
      setChore(e.currentTarget.value)
  }
  const handleDateChange = (e:React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>)=> {
      e.preventDefault()
      setDate(e.currentTarget.value)
  }
```

What's a more succinct way of writing this? I know when using the `setState` method that you can write it as

```
this.setState({
[name]: [e.target.value]
})
```

...so what's the equivalent when using the `useState` hook?

Here's the component in full:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Document from './Document'
import './styles.css'

interface Formatter {
  format(): string
}

class ChoreDoc implements Formatter  {
  name:string
  chore:string
  date:string

  constructor(n:string,c:string,d:string){
    this.name = n
    this.chore = c
    this.date = d
  }

  format(){
    return `${this.name} completed this following chore: ${this.chore} (on date: ${this.date})`
  }
}

function App() {

  const [name, setName] = useState('')
  const [chore, setChore] = useState('')
  const [date, setDate] = useState('')
  const [document, setDocument] = useState<ChoreDoc | null>(null);
  const [choreList, setChoreList] = useState<Array<ChoreDoc>>([])

  const handleNameChange = (e:React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
      e.preventDefault()
      setName(e.currentTarget.value)
  }
  const handleChoreChange = (e:React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
      e.preventDefault()
      setChore(e.currentTarget.value)
  }
  const handleDateChange = (e:React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>)=> {
      e.preventDefault()
      setDate(e.currentTarget.value)
  }


  const handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>)=> {
    e.preventDefault()
    let doc = new ChoreDoc(name,chore,date)
    setDocument(doc)
    setChoreList([...choreList,doc])
  }


  return(
    <>
      <div>
          <form className = 'input-list' onSubmit = {handleSubmit} >
              <label>
              Enter Name <br></br>
              <input type = 'text' name = 'name' onChange = {handleNameChange}></input>
              </label>
              <label>
              Chore <br></br>
              <input type = 'text' name = 'chore' onChange = {handleChoreChange}></input>
              </label>
              <label>
              Date completed <br></br>
              <input type = 'text' name = 'date' onChange = {handleDateChange}></input>
              </label>
              <div>
              <button type = 'submit' >Submit</button>
              </div>
          </form>
      </div>
      <div>
        {
          choreList.map(chore => {
            return <Document document = {chore}/>
          })
        }
      </div>
      </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a few ways to skin this. You may want to consider a form hook lib that would help maintain the form model. You can take a look at [React Hook Form](https://react-hook-form.com/) for that. However here's one approach.

*Removing all but form inputs here so it's a little more clear, let me know if you have further questions.*

**See comment above "onFormChange" below for more details**

When the form is submitted you you can grab your "chore" model and use it as you wish as it will already be in the shape of your interface. Cheers!

```
interface IChore {
  name: string;
  chore: string;
  date: string;
}

function App() {

  const [chore, setChore] = useState({} as IChore);

  // NOTE: all we're doing here is passing in the key that we
  // want to update, this returns a function which accepts the
  // change event (you can add your typings if you wish). When
  // the event is fired we already have the context with the 
  // key we want to update. At that point it's just simple 
  // destructuring of the current object and then we add 
  // the new updated value. 

  const onFormChange = (key) => (e) => {
    setChore({ ...chore, [key]: e.currentTarget.value });
  };
  
  return (
       <div>

         <form className = 'input-list' onSubmit = {handleSubmit} >
       
          <input type = 'text' name = 'name' onChange = {onFormChange('name')} />
          
          <input type = 'text' name = 'chore' onChange = {onFormChange('chore')}/>
           
          <input type = 'text' name = 'date' onChange = {onFormChange('date')} />
           
          <div>
              <button type = 'submit' >Submit</button>
          </div>

        </form>

      </div>
  );

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to break your form into multiple states. you can still use the same logic as before with one form state handler:

```
const [{ name, chore, date }, setForm] = useState({name: '', chore: '', date: ''})

  const handleFormChange = (e:React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
      e.preventDefault()
      const { name, value } = e.target
      setForm(prevForm => ({
        ...prevForm,
        [name]: value
      }))
  }
```

if you prefer to break states, other option could be pass the setState handler as second argument:

```
const handleStateChange = (e:React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>, setStateHandler) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  setStateHandler(e.currentTarget.value)
}

<input type = 'text' name = 'name' onChange = {(e) => handleStateChange(e, setName)}></input>
```